# Read attributes passed with href tag in JNLP

Tags: java, dynamic, jnlp, java-web-start

I am passing dynamic values with href tag in dynamically generated jnlp using jsp.

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://10.40.42.134:8080/TestJNLP/" href="test.jnlp?arg1=<%=request.getParameter("arg1")%>&arg2=<%=request.getParameter("arg2")%>">
```

AFAIK when user will download and run this JNLP it will hit the server based on codebase and href attributes and for getting JNLP and jar but how to read `arg1` and `arg2` in JNLP present on my server.

What should argument tags of my JNLP (which is present on the server) look like 
whether they should be of format `<argument>"$$arg1"</argument>`
or of the form `<argument><%=request.getParameter("arg1")%></argument>` or some other format.

Can some please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further exploring the options I found that dynamic JNLP can be made using JSP which in turn can have `request.getParameter(arg)`

JSP structure would look like

```
<argument><%=request.getParameter("arg1")%></argument>
```

and response type as `application/x-java-jnlp-file`